# firefox object height ignored when data

Tags: html, flash, firefox, object

I have a flash video loading in a modal window. It works in others browsers but not Firefox. Firefox opens the modal window to the correct width of the object, but with no height. I have come to learn that Firefox does not recognize `<param>` and instead uses the `data` attribute. However, when I remove this attribute, the modal opens with correct height. What is going on? Here is the code the modal window loads:

```
<object width="720" height="520" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="proxymovie.SWF?file=proxymovie.MP4">
    <param name="movie" value="proxymovie.SWF?file=proxymovie.MP4" />
    <img src="images/poster.png" width="720" height="480" alt="" title="Download the video below" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox ignores `object` and uses `embed`. Do you have the height set on the `embed` tag?

Answer (score 0):

I tried `embed` earlier to no avail.

```
<object width="720" height="520" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="proxymovie.SWF?file=proxymovie.MP4">
<param name="movie" value="proxymovie.SWF?file=proxymovie.MP4" />
<embed src="proxymovie.swf?file=proxymovie.mp4" width="720" height="520" />
```

I should clarify that the flash video is there and I can scroll down, but it only shows a sliver of the top in the modal window.

Comment: Try setting the dimensions of the containers via css: 
<embed style="display:block;width:720px;height:520px;">